# Why serverless-next.js doesn't create lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, server-side-rendering, serverless

I have created simple next.js app and used [this library](https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js) for deploy it with s3, cloudfront and lambdas. 
`articles/[articleId].tsx` file has `getServerSideProps` function, so I need lambda to render this page. I run 'serverless', it deployed and **IT WORKS**. But I don't see any lambda function in aws console.

So, how it works then?..

Answer (score 1):

From [their readme](https://github.com/danielcondemarin/serverless-next.js#lambda-at-edge-configuration) it seems that they are using [lambda@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html).

So its likely your lambda functions will be also lambda@edge and these are in `us-east-1` (N. Virginia) region. Thus you should **switch your console to the `us-east-1` region** and look for the functions there.